# How can I track values between Jenkins Builds (Static Analysis)

Tags: jenkins, static-analysis

I'm running a number of static analysis tools and I want to track the results from build to build. For example, if a commit to a branch increases the number of security vulnerabilities, I want to send an email to the committer. I know there are plugins like Sonar and Analysis Collector, but they don't cover all of the areas of analysis I want and they don't seem to have the ability to trigger actions based on build trends (correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Groovy Postbuild Plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin

It lets you extract data (such as number of vulnerabilities detected) from the current build's buildlog with `num_vul = manager.getLogMatcher(regexp)`

And compare that to previous builds, by extracting info from their buildlog, e.g.:

```
currentBuildNumber = manager.build.number
manager.setBuildNumber(currentBuildNumber - 1)
prev_num_vul = manager.getLogMatcher(regexp)
```

Then, if the number of vulnerabilities had gone up, I would call `manager.buildFailure()` which sets the build status to FAILURE, and then have the next PostBuild step be to the Email-ext plugin which allows you to send email to the committer in the event of a failure.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) tool, which does just what you describe. You mention that you already looked at it, but maybe you missed the [Notifications feature](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Notifications) or the [Build Breaker Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Breaker+Plugin). There are more SonarQube features centered around Jenkins integration. SonarQube is free to use.

If you are still missing something, it might be worthwhile asking specifically how that aspect could be covered by SonarQube. Just my two cents.

Comment: Thanks, the Notifications feature looks useful, but I'm looking for a more generic method of tracking as SonarQube has some holes in what it covers. It looks like they have some pretty active interest, though, so hopefully some of those holes will get filled in.